# PHP SQL no results with strings

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I am currently using PHP and SQL to throw back some paramters I enter in a form.

I can search numbers perfectly fine and it gives me the correct results but anytime I use a search like "443265dsa44dd" it displays nothing even though it's in the database.

```
$searchedID = $_POST['uuid'];
$sql = "SELECT name, contact, phone, address FROM test WHERE id = '.$searchedID.'";


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo "Name: " . $row["name"] . "<br>" . "Contact: " . $row["contact"] . "<br>" . "Phone: " . $row["phone"] . "<br>" . "Address: " . $row["address"] . " ";
     }
}
```

The id is a primary key and set to VARCHAR, any ideas what is happening here?

Comment: please use prepared statements, you are vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: As per this code, you're not executing the query. You also have some excessive dots near your variable, `'.$searchedID.'";` - either remove the dots, or break out of the string like `='".$searchedID."'";`

Comment: @Brrrr I will be santeising once I get this working :D,

Comment: Thanks @Qirel I will give that a shot

Comment: @Nathan: If you would have used prepared statements in first place, this error wouldn't have happened!

Comment: @Qirel Here's a beer my friend!! I'm still learning the basics and sometimes concatinating things together can get confusing.

Comment: @Nathan *Cheers* :-) Using a proper texteditor with proper highlighting can help with catching mistakes like that, as you can see here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Nathan If an answer helped you or solved your problem you can accept it, which helps those who gave the answer. In this case it's me, in future it could be you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error when trying to include the searchedID into the sql-string.

Either concat like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, contact, phone, address FROM test WHERE id = '" . $searchedID . "'"
// note, the additional quotes
```

OR

let php parse that var for you (possible only inside double-quotes):

```
$sql = "SELECT name, contact, phone, address FROM test WHERE id = '$searchedID'"
```

**BUT**
You are vulnerable to sql-injection. So use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)!